# Existence of measurable "inclusion" into Euclidean space

Tags: reference-request, measure-theory, boolean-algebras

Let $(\Omega,\mathfrak{F})$ be a measurable space.  When does there exist an injective measurable function $f:(\Omega,\mathfrak{F})\to (\mathbb{R}^n,B(\mathbb{R}^n))$ to some Euclidean space, here $B(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.

Thoughts.  Clearly, if $\Omega$ is a Riemannian manifold and $\mathfrak{F}$ is its Borel $\sigma$-algebra then this works but I'm thinking of more general, non-topological criteria.  (If they exist)

Comment: Such a function (in fact, bijective) exists  as soon as $\Omega $ is an uncountable polish space  — this is the Borel isomorphism theorem.

Comment: In general, we can stick to $n=1$.

Comment: @abx: Since only injectivity is requested here, any separable metrizable space will do.  In particular, a non-measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with its Borel $\sigma$-algebra will do.  Actually, submetrizable is enough.

Comment: @Nate Eldredge: Yes, right.

Comment: @abx  I did not know this result, thanks.

Comment: @NateEldredge  I never heard of submetrizable, but I assume it can be worked out directly from the theorem abx provided?

Comment: @AIM_BLB: Yes.  A submetrizable space, by definition, has a continuous injection into a metric space, which in turn has a continuous injection into its completion, which as abx noted has a bimeasurable bijection to $\mathbb{R}$ assuming separability in the right places.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Basically the same as Michael's answer)

Theorem 6.5.7 of *Measure Theory* by V. Bogachev:

> **Theorem.** The following are equivalent:
>
> 1. $\mathfrak{F}$ is *countably separated* (Bogachev Definition 6.5.1 (ii)): there exists an at most countable collection of sets $F_n \in \mathfrak{F}$ such that for every two distinct points $x,y \in \Omega$, there is some $F_n$ with $x \in F_n$, $y \notin F_n$;
> 2. there is an injective measurable function $f : \Omega \to [0,1]$ (or equivalently, to $\mathbb{R}^n$, since they are Borel isomorphic to $[0,1]$);
> 3. The diagonal $\Delta = \{(x,x) : x \in \Omega\}$ is measurable with respect to the product $\sigma$-algebra $\mathfrak{F} \otimes\mathfrak{F}$;
> 4. There exists a separable (i.e. countably generated) sub-$\sigma$-algebra $\mathfrak{F}_0 \subset \mathfrak{F}$ which contains all the singletons.

Answer (score 4):

This is the case if and only if there exists a countable subfamily of $\mathfrak{F}$ that separates points. Necessity is straightforward; if such a function exists then the preimages of rectangles with rational coordinates at the endpoints will serve as the countable separating family.

For sufficiency, let $\mathcal{C}=\{C_1, C_2,\ldots\}$ be a countable separating family of measurable sets. Then the Marczewski function $f:\Omega\to [0,1]$ given by $f(\omega)=\sum_n 2/3^n1_{C_n}(\omega)$ will be measurable and injective.